# Why online Jquery Datepicker work, but local Jquery Datepicker not work in MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have issue in MVC project.

I already tested in **create.cshtml** by add this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

and for the textbox input :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

and it worked, when i click or keypress on textbox, datepicker popup is show up.

but when i want this javascript and css file run locally in my pc by put **in _layout.cshtml** (behave as general in all page) :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and remark the direct link to jquery online (source) in my create.cshtml , after that i run that page doesn't show up the datepicker, is i missing something for this issue ?

ps: i already save the jquery-1.9.1.js , jquery-ui.js , jquery-ui.css in my local pc

Comment: the path you have mentioned for your local jquery files are not correct

Comment: Use chrome inspector to find the correct path.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' i already use phoenix editor to see what file that run in firefox, file .js and .css is loaded, but still not work.

Comment: @Ankur140290 , how to use chrome inspector ? i already test in chrome but have the same result

Comment: @DeddyH Just Press `F12` key, It will open inspecter. Then refresh the  page and press `Esc`, This will show you all the missing paths and errors in your code. For fore read this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @Ankur140290, ok thank you for your guide. i already found the solution.

Comment: This issue because when i put this code in page View , it placed in position before </head>, and when i put in page layout, it placed in position before </body>, the point is the reference file need to be put in head position, so Jquery will work as we need. Thank all for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your path of file missing on local.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: is not like that, the first code work properly, but when i remark that code and add the link in _layout.cshtml , 
`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`
then create page is not work properly [it seem .js is not work global]